# How to create a forest plot with python or excel?

Tags: python, excel, forest-plots

I am new to python/excel and would like to create a forest plot that looks like this.
   [image: Template of forest plot I am trying to create]

My dataset contains 3 columns, the first is the label (name of subjects), the next two are for example exam scores for highest and lowest students. I want the students that with the least score to be on the lest side of the line while those who scored highest to be on the right of same line representing subjects. This will be for all subjects. How do i do this?

Comment: Various solutions are discussed in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65197025/2550702